# Mongo connector with neo4j doc manager crashing

Tags: mongodb, neo4j

I'm using mongo-connector and neo4j_doc_manager for syncing the mongodb's data to neo4j, it used to work perfectly but today it started giving following error.

```
2016-07-29 17:18:59,558 [CRITICAL] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:549 - Exception during collection dump
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/oplog_manager.py", line 501, in do_dump
    upsert_all(dm)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/oplog_manager.py", line 485, in upsert_all
    dm.bulk_upsert(docs_to_dump(namespace), mapped_ns, long_ts)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 38, in wrapped
    reraise(new_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 32, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/neo4j_doc_manager.py", line 89, in bulk_upsert
    tx.commit()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 306, in commit
    return self.post(self.__commit or self.__begin_commit)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/core.py", line 261, in post
    raise self.error_class.hydrate(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py2neo/cypher/error/core.py", line 54, in hydrate
    error_cls = getattr(error_module, title)
Neo4jOperationFailed: 'module' object has no attribute 'ConstraintValidationFailed'
2016-07-29 17:18:59,563 [ERROR] mongo_connector.oplog_manager:557 - OplogThread: Failed during dump collection cannot recover!
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to insert data which doesn't match the [constraints of your Neo4j schema](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.0/#query-constraints) (unicity or existence), and apparently the code doesn't know how to handle that type of error, though it does give its name:

> ConstraintValidationFailed

You should maybe activate some log to see the data which it is trying to insert, or the Cypher query it's trying to execute.